# Expression in terms of $N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find the closed form expression in terms of $N$

$\sum_{t=1}^{N} \sum_{i=1}^{t} \sum_{k=1}^{i} (tik)$.

Thank you for good idea.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $\sum_{n=1}^N n$? This looks like a mild generalization of such formulas.

Comment: The formula is $n*(n+1)/2 $. Is it true ? But is not clear in this question for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in three steps:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^i (ti) k = ti  \sum_{k=1}^i k = \frac12 i^2 (1+i) t
$$
then 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^t  \frac12 i^2 (1+i) t = \frac12 t \sum_{i=1}^t i^2 (1+i)
=  \frac12 t \left( \sum_{i=1}^t (i+2) (1+i) i -\sum_{i=1}^t 2 (1+i) i\right)  \\
=   \frac12 t \left( \frac14 t(t+1)(t+2)(t+3) - \frac23 t^2(t+1)(t+2)\right) \\=\frac1{24} t^2(t+1)(t+2)(3t+1)
$$
Finally, using the same technique of breaking up into sums that all involve rising powers (of $t$ this time),
$$
\frac1{24} t^2(t+1)(t+2)(3t+1) = \frac1{48}N^2(N+1)^2(N+2)(N+3)
$$
and that is your answer.